# How to customize docker container's volume and port after it finished its first execution?

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, centos7

I am a newbie to docker (containerization stuff). I am trying to learn docker in GCP (CentOS 7 instance) and to containerization my simple interactive python program. I successfully created a docker image for my python program.

My doubt is when I run

> docker run -it  **my image name**

A container is spinned up with a random name call "classy-brown"
and my program executed successfully ...and no issue with that.

The thing is, is there any way to add port & volume for my existing container i.e("classy-brown")

And every time when I run this  command

> docker run -it  **my image name**

A new container is created? And why its doing it me?

Please help me out with this.

Comment: After you're done with your container, you can `docker rm` it.  If you want different options, specify them on the next `docker run` invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't setup a volume or a port on already created container. You can use `docker start -it <container_id> or <conatiner_name>` to use a container multiple times interactively.

If you want to setup a volume or port on a container, you should to it during the container creation using [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command like this;

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v /home/somedir:/foo --name my_container
```

if you want to use the same container over and over again, just use the [docker start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) command.

```
docker start -it my_container
```

Please note, `-it` for interactive access either on `docker start` or `docker run`. If you don't want to access the container with `tty` just omit the `-it` flags.

If you want to access already running container, you can use `docker exec` command. More about it you can find [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to StackOverflow.
You can pass the "--name" parameter when you start a container, to give it a custom name.

Also, you may use the '-p' option to expose specific ports.

Have a look at this page to see all the `docker run` options -

https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

A new port mapping can be added by manually editing **iptable rules**, but I don't think it is a good practice. Besides, if you run `docker ps`, this newly-added mapping will not be visible.

---

If you **REALY** need to add port mappings or mount volumes to your already running container. You can [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) this container to an image by

```
docker commit <container-id>
```

Stop and remove your container, and then run the new image with `-p` and `-v` like:

```
docker run -p <port-mapping> -v <mount> <commited-image>
```

Note that `commit` can cost a lot of time if your container is large(a lot of data in container layer).

> Don't rely on this kind of approach too much, but think twice before you run your container.

Good luck!